# Minimum number of subintervals M for the Composite Midpoint Rule

Tags: integration

I am trying to find the minimum number $M$ of subintervals for the composite midpoint rule to approximate $$\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}dx$$ with an absolute error less than $10^{-4}$.

I know that the error can be given by $$E(f)=\frac{b-a}{24}f''(c)h^2$$ where $a,b$ are the endpoint of the interval, $c\in(a,b)$ and $h$ is the width of each subinterval. However, I cannot seem to find a maximum for $f''(c)$ since I get $$f''(x)=\frac{1}{\left(\left(1-x\right)x\right)^\frac{3}{2}}+\frac{3\left(2x-1\right)^2}{4\left(\left(1-x\right)x\right)^\frac{5}{2}}$$ which has no maximum since it approaches infinity as x approaches either 0 or 1.

Does this mean that there is no solution?